# Hibernate OneToMany concept

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have schools and students as entity concept, where one school can have multiple students and one student can only have one school. This is mapped as bidirectional relation in `Hibernate` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "SCHOOL" )
public class School
{
   @Id
   @Type( type = "uuid-char" )
   @Column( name = "SCHOOL_ID_",
            unique = true,
            nullable = false )
   private UUID schoolId_;

   @OneToMany( mappedBy = "school_",
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               orphanRemoval = true,
               fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
   private List< Student > students_;

(...)


@Entity
@Table( name = "STUDENT" )
public class Student
{
   @Id
   @Type( type = "uuid-char" )
   @Column( name = "STUDENT_ID_",
            unique = true,
            nullable = false )
   private UUID studentId_;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn( name = "SCHOOL_ID_",
                nullable = false )
   private School school_;
```

I decided to use this bidirectional relation to benefit from automatic cascading, so that i can delete a school and its students are deleted automatically without having orphaned database entries.

My question is now, whether this concept is modelled correctly as representation of the real-world purpose described above and beneficial in regards of performance in `Hibernate`. I read in several articles, that hibernate does create unnecessary queries for lookups and removals, when not mapped bidirectional.

Comment: Is that a typo in student entity? I think you meant to add School instead of Student in Student.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i fixed it.